# Cannot resolve the return value from a client object WebService

Tags: c#, web-services

I don't understand how to fix this issue. I will need your help and explanation on how to fix it.
I used a WebService to populate a DropDownList with artist names.
Here is the code behing.

```
private List<ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient> ArtistDetail()
{
    ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient client =  
      new ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient();

    ArtistServiceReference.Artist[] artists = client.ArtistDetail();

    return artists.ToList();   <=== errror here
```

Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<ArtistServiceReference.Artist>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient>`

Here is the ArtistService.cs

```
public class ArtistService : IArtistService
{
    public List<Artist>  ArtistDetail()   
    {
        using (ArtistDataContext db = new ArtistDataContext())
        {
            return (from artist in db.Artists

                select new Artist()
                {
                    Id = artist.Id,
                    Artist_nom = artist.Artist_nom
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't let me returning a ToList() to populate my dropdownlist

Comment: _Read the error message_.  It's telling you exactly what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I am new to C#, how to convert it then if it is not allowed?

Comment: You need to return the same type that you're actually getting.

Comment: @user3127986 You've got the same problem in three different questions - you are tryiong to return a collection of the _service reference_ instead of the _entity_

Answer (score 1):

If you want your client method to return a list of `Artist`s, why do you declare it as returning a list of `ArtistClient`s?

The following should fix your issue:

```
private List<ArtistServiceReference.Artist> ArtistDetail()
{
    ...
    return artists.ToList();
}
```

or, even more elegant:

```
using YourNamespace.ArtistServiceReference;

private List<Artist> ArtistDetail()
{
    ...
    return artists.ToList();
}
```

Comment: If I do this change I got this error at the end }).ToList();    Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Artist>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ArtistServiceReference.Artist>'      If I remove the ToList()  I got an error at the Select  Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Artist>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ArtistServiceReference.Artist>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: It sounds like you have a second class named `Artist`. In that case, use the first version with the fully qualified name.

Comment: the program compile now but I got  an error at the linq Explicit construction of entity type 'Artist' in query is not allowed the error is in the ArtistService.cs at the end }).ToList();  see the commnents from the user below

Comment: @user3127986: That's a different bug, you might want to start a new question on that. Your client is fine now. The problem on your server is that `Artist` is a LINQ-to-SQL entity, which cannot be created explicitly. You can either replace the whole `select ...` block with just `select artist).ToList();` or replace `new Artist...` with `new MyNamespace.Artist...`, if you want to create a *different* `Artist` object.

Comment: The example which I am following is doing what I did but it is returning to a gridview instead of a dropdownlist.  You are saying we cannot create explicitly this, I am confuse now.  The example I am following should not work also then ?

Answer (score 1):

Your return type on your method should be a list of ArtistServiceReference.Artist as opposed to a list of ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient. You want to return a list of Artists by using the ArtistServiceClient, you are not returning a list of the clients.

```
private List<ArtistServiceReference.Artist> ArtistDetail()
{
    ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient client =  
      new ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient();

    var artists = client.ArtistDetail();

    return artists.ToList();
}
```

Comment: It let me compile but I got an error at the linq Explicit construction of entity type 'Artist' in query is not allowed  the error is in the ArtistService.cs at the end  }).ToList();

Comment: You need to actually perform the service call. client.ArtistDetail() is an object type as far as I can tell and it isn't actually hitting the service to retrieve any Artists.

Comment: The example I follow to perform this was using the default.aspx.cs.  My site is having multiple pages. The page where I put the call is Apointement.aspx.cs. which is only load when a user is log on.  To build the list should I move my client ArtistDetail() to the default page.aspx.cs ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. Your issue now is that the variable type os "artists" is incorrect. You are calling client.ArtistDetail() which you have returning a list of Artist, but you are trying to assign that to an array of ArtistServiceReference.Artist.

Comment: client.VoitureDetail().ToArray();  did not fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

code behind.cs

```
private List<ArtistServiceReference.Artist> ArtistDetail()
{
    ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient client = new 
    ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient();

    ArtistServiceReference.Voiture[] artists = client.ArtistDetail();

    return artists.ToList();
}
```

ArtistService.cs

```
public class ArtistService : IArtistService
{
    public List<Artist>  ArtistDetail()  
    {
        using (ArtistDataContext db = new ArtistDataContext())
        {
            return db.Artists.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```